# How to get Visual Studio to Fetch incoming commits automatically

Tags: git, visual-studio

So when using Git in MSVS you can use Fetch to see what incoming commits are waiting on you. Is there a way to set this to happen automatically, or am I forced to click on Fetch every time I think about it?

Comment: Fundamentally this would be a polling process since git, at least by default, doesn't have push notifications for new commits.  Why not just schedule a task to run `git fetch` every X minutes?

Comment: VS Code does this; it would be nice if Visual Studio did as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a different but approaching need (I used git-tf on a big project, `git tf fetch` was taking too long, so I did it in the background to speed up `git tf pull` command). I poll every 10 minutes, and show the differences visually in the command line. Maybe this can help you:

[image: Git background fetch]

I use a powershell script to poll:

```
function backgroundfetch
{
    while ($true)
    {
        # Get latest
        git fetch;
        # Clear console
        cls;
        # Leave space for progress bar
        for ($i=0; $i -le 6; $i++) {Write-Host;} 
        # Show commit differences between master and origin/master
        git lgori;
        # Show progress bar before next fetch
        for ($i=0; $i -le 1000; $i++)
        {
                Write-Progress -Activity "Sleeping" -status ("{0:0.00} minutes remaining" -f ((1000-$i)/100)) -percentComplete ($i/10);
                Start-Sleep -s 0.6;
        }
    }
}
```

And 2 git aliases

- `git lg`: a pretty `git log` alias with graph
- `git lgori`: to show visually the commit differences between master and origin/master, using the first alias

in .gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    lg = log --graph --format=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(bold white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold blue)%d%C(reset)' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
    lgori = !git lg HEAD origin/master --not `git merge-base HEAD origin/master`^
```