# Notify on incoming commits in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

Is there an extension to visual studio which will notify me when there are new commits pushed to my branch?

I like how Visual Studio Code shows "incomming commits" in the status bar and I miss this feature in Visual Studio.

The reason I would like to be notified is that I usually want to pull incomming commits as soon as possible so I can avoid merge commits.

Comment: If you mark it as off topic, write a comment at least why you think it's off topic, please! I'm not asking to recommend a "best" tool, which would lead to opinionated answer. I'm trying to solve a problem related to programming which definitelly can have non-opinionated anwers

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't have push notifications for new commits. You could run git fetch every several minutes. Following thread introduce how to poll every several minutes with powershell script.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22013151/6593307

Comment: Ok, I guess VS Code checks upstream branch every few minutes. However, the powershell does not help be much with my problem, since it does not notify me. And I don't like running / stopping the powershell each time I open / close visual studio solution

Comment: @Liero I suggest you create your customer extensions which call above powershell script with C#. Then you could prompt you through this extension in Visual Studio.